# как отправить .txt файл через телеграмм бота

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Код:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    searcher = message.text.find("Guess_")
    if searcher != -1:
        await 
    else:
        await message.answer("Ещё не добавлен исходник")
```

Comment: И в чём у вас проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть так:

```
    @dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    searcher = message.text.find("Guess_")
    if searcher != -1:
        await bot.send_document(message.chat.id, open(r'Путь к файлу', 'rb'))
    else:
        await message.answer("Ещё не добавлен исходник")
```